# C# How to best add elements of string array to generic List

Tags: c#

If I have an array of strings such as:

```
string[] strArr = {"First", "Second", "Third"};
```

...and I want to add these to a generic List

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
```

what is the best way to go about it?

**Option 1**:
Loop with for or foreach, using `.Add` method.

**Option 2**:
`.AddRange` method (ref example on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
strList.AddRange = new List<string>(strArr);
```

Or other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an IEnumerable:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>(strArr);
```

or call `ToList()` on your array:

```
List<string> strList = strArr.ToList();
```

which is probably the most common way to do it.

Comment: i do not see the method  array.ToList()    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0        It also gets flagged as an error .     new List<string>(ary)  does work

Comment: ToList() is an extension off IEnumerable<T> from System.Linq namespace

Comment: I was not inlcuding linq namespace, thanks